# War deployment using puppet in Jboss

Tags: jboss, puppet

I have deployed the war in Jboss using puppet command and i checked the `/standalone/deployments` folder to check my `.war` file but i don't see any `.war` file there inside `/standalone/deployments` folder:

```
/opt/puppetlabs/bin/puppet apply --basemodulepath=/opt/alu/deploy/puppet/modules/ --hiera_config=/opt/install/hiera.yaml --execute ' class { profiles::jboss: }'
```

Ideally when we are doing manual deployment of `.war` file , we are putting the `.war` file inside `/standalone/deployments` folder.

My question is where can i check the `.war` which has deployed using `puppet` in Jboss server. My Jboss version is `6.0`

Comment: What *Puppet* code and `puppet` command are you using to deploy your file?

Comment: @JohnBollinger -- I am using this puppet command 
/opt/puppetlabs/bin/puppet   apply   --basemodulepath=/opt/alu/deploy/puppet/modules/ --hiera_config=/opt/install/hiera.yaml --execute ' class { profiles::jboss: }' --debug

Comment: Yes you can, depending on what is this `profiles::jboss` class you're referencing does. You can run the `puppet apply` with a `--debug` flag. Also you can list the `catalog` with `--write-catalog-summary` (more on: https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/man/apply.html). You can also put here the `profile::jboss` code snippet and the URL to the `jboss` puppet module you're using (if used from the forge)

Answer (score 0):

Just complementing the answer, you can deploy directly on Jboss with a cli command and/or see the deployment status/content using the following commands:

```
    #deployment-info 
    NAME          RUNTIME-NAME  PERSISTENT ENABLED STATUS 
    hibernate.war hibernate.war false      true    OK 


    #deployment=hibernate.war:read-attribute(name=content)
    {
        "outcome" => "success",
        "result" => [{"hash" => bytes {
            0x29, 0x93, 0x46, 0x13, 0xdd, 0x74, 0xff, 0x1d,
            0xb7, 0x6e, 0xa6, 0xde, 0x60, 0xb3, 0x85, 0xf6,
            0xae, 0x72, 0xc9, 0x0f
        }}]
    }



Q: Where can i check the .war which has deployed using puppet in Jboss server
A: You don't need another tool.
```